# storing multiple controls and update radio button values?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

What am doing here is; making a UI to update values visually, will add more support for other types too. Possibly all types.
updateIcons this function is called everytime the controller is loaded, and has new values,names everytime.
countControls to keep track of controllers, so if can update values on clicks.
myP is the object that holds the values taken at runtime, user shuffles values by pressing tab from another screen
created radiobuttons groupboxes to allow radiobutton group to be managed.
properties all belong to one object. each property has few possible values like in my example, the enums.

now am kinda lost, not sure how to best do this, as now my rb_CheckedChanged is returning some kind of mess.
How do i do this the right way ? all together, i feel its somewhat the right approach At least.
I thought of making a dictionary of ? to use it at the checked event. not exactly sure how

```
 private void updateIcons(List<Props> prop) {
  countControls++;
  locationY = 10;
  int gbHeight;
 foreach (var p in prop) {
radioButtonY = 10;
IType pType = p.Type;
if (pType is Enum) {
  var myP = new MyProp(p, this);
  GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
  gb.Location = new Point(nextLocationX,locationY);
  nextLocationX += rbWidth+10;
  gb.Name = "groupBox" + countControls;
  gb.Text = "smthn";
  var TypesArray = set here;

gbHeight = TypesArray.Length;
foreach (var type in TypesArray) {
  getimagesPath(TypesArray);
  RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
  rb.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
  rb.Width = rbWidth;
  rb.Height = rbHeight;
  rb.Name = type.Name + countControls;
  rb.Text = type.Name;
  string path = imagePaths[type.Name];
  Bitmap rbImage = new Bitmap(path);
  rb.BackgroundImage = rbImage;
  countControls++;
  rb.Location = new Point(radioButtonX, radioButtonY);

  if (myP.Value != null && type.Name.SafeEquals(myP.Value.ToString())) {
    rb.Checked = true;

  }
  radioButtonY += rbHeight;
  gb.Controls.Add(rb);
  rb.CheckedChanged += rb_CheckedChanged;

}
gb.Height = rbHeight * gbHeight + 20;
gb.Width = rbWidth + 10;

Controls.Add(gb);
}
}
}

void rb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
  Control control = (Control)sender;

  if (rb.Checked) {
    MessageBox.Show("You have just checked: " + rb.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("You have just called Controller: " + control.Name);
    var t = PropSeq;
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("you have just unchecked: " + rb.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("You have just called Controller: " + control.Name);
  }


}
```

Comment: My head hurts... :-) When do you think they will be disposed? What is their life-span?

Comment: Oh, I didn't take that into considerations coz I didn't know how that works :D I just have the default dispose function at the bottom of everything :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code might be a little messed up and not the easiest to read. It looks plain invalid with not all closing braces present? Try the code below which will create two group boxes, each with five radio buttons. This should help you achieve what you are trying to do (full listing for a basic Form):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateButton();
        }

        private void CreateButton() 
        {
            // Add two group boxes
            for (int groupCount = 1; groupCount < 3; groupCount++)
            {
                var groupBox = new GroupBox();
                groupBox.Location = new Point(220 * (groupCount - 1), 10);
                groupBox.Name = string.Format("groupBox{0}", groupCount);
                groupBox.Text = string.Format("Group Box {0}", groupCount);

                // Add some radio buttons to each
                for (int buttonCount = 1; buttonCount < 6; buttonCount++)
                {
                    var radioButton = new RadioButton();
                    radioButton.Width = 150;
                    radioButton.Location = new Point(10, 30 * buttonCount);
                    radioButton.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
                    radioButton.Name = string.Format("radioButton{0}", buttonCount);
                    radioButton.Text = string.Format("Dynamic Radio Button {0} - {1}", groupCount, buttonCount);
                    radioButton.CheckedChanged += radioButton_CheckedChanged;

                    // Add radio button to the group box
                    groupBox.Controls.Add(radioButton);
                    groupBox.Height += 20;
                }

                // Add group box to form
                Controls.Add(groupBox);
            }               
        }

        private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get button and only show the selected (not now de-selected item)
            var radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
            if (radioButton.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have just checked: " + radioButton.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i will rewrite my code better. But my problem is, since I don't know how many buttons i will have in each groupbox, also not the groupbox amount. they are all at runtime, dynamic. So when I have my radiobutton click function like above. It doesn't seem to respone. perhaps it's not sure which groupbox, control to respond to ?

Comment: surprisingly this code works up to this problem :P its like that coz am intensively experimenting at this stage.. thanks if you can help with this problem :)

Comment: The code I provided is adding dynamic controls? I just added a fixed amount to make life easier but it could be 0 to Random really. Can you update your code to one that actually compiles so I can take another look? It should work as long as you are adding as in my example?

Comment: thanks @Belogix that did help me, but still confused on my version though, hope you can help

Comment: Can you post your project somewhere so I can see it in context please?

Comment: Am sorry, I actually can't, am developing this indipendently at the moment, but are there any details I can try to provide ?

Comment: Sorry, then I can't really help any more. The sample I gave should allow you to do exactly what you want and just place it into your code as needed. The sample works so you should be able to use that to determine why yours doesn't.